# Azure policy - prevent the creation of app services without authentication

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I wish to create a policy that will prevent the creation of app services without authentication enabled (just auditing them is not enough).

The following policy can correctly identify **existing** resources that do not have authentication enabled:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthEnabled",
          "equals": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}
```

however it does not prevent them being created in the first place (either via ARM template or through the portal).

I suspect this is because the `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` resource isn't being explicitly created.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/*` resource type (except `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web`) is not supported by Azure Policy at this point.

Quoting [@camillemarie](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/264#issuecomment-444312001) from [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/264) similar GitHub issue:

> **authSettings** cannot be managed via policy at this time. In the interest of hiding secrets from users in the default Reader role, this resource provider doesn't expose secrets via GET calls (hence the *null* in /config/web, and lack of GET support for /config/authSettings).
>
> This means that the existing Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthSettings.* aliases are invalid. We'll look into removing these, but we don't have a good deprecation story at the moment.

Reference:

- [Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthSettings.* aliases are not valid #264](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/264)
- [Azure Policy - Known Issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy#known-issues)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Microsoft.Web/sites/siteConfig alias.

Comment: There are no valid aliases for site authentication under siteConfig.
The only valid aliases/fields are Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthSettings and Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthEnabled